# How to get all columns in clause selectRaw?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I've a `users` table and foreach one of them, there are many `image` corresponding be save in `images` table with foreign key `user_id`.

I want to get all data from `users` table and count quantity of their image, and this code is working:

```
$out = Users::join('images','images.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->selectRaw('users.id, users.name, count(*) as quantity')->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

Results example:

```
[{'id'=>1,'name'=>'Rome','quantity':2},
{'id'=>2,'name'=>'Rome','quantity':5},....
]
```

My `users` table have many columns such as: `email, role`, etc, and sometime i must repair its struct, so i have to change many time the string in clause `selectRaw`.

My question is: how to change the string in clause `selectRaw` to get all columns from `users` table, pseudocode look like:

`selectRaw('* from users, count(*) as quantity')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$out = Users::join('images','images.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->selectRaw('users.*, count(images.user_id) as quantity')->groupBy('images.user_id')->get();
```